# mysql error 1064 while importing the sql file to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USER_TRACKS;
USE USER_TRACKS;


CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE(

userId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR(10),
lastName VARCHAR(10),
contactNo VARCHAR(20),
emailId VARCHAR(30),
pass VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE USER_MUSIC_CATALOGUE(

userId INT REFERENCES USER_TABLE(userId),
generType VARCHAR(20),
albumName VARCHAR(20),
artistName VARCHAR(20),
releaseDate DATE
);
```

I get Error #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax each time i try to import the database. But I dont know how the syntax is wrong. Please help!?

Comment: this query are ok. which version you are using " IF NOT EXISTS" : post the output from - SELECT VERSION();

Comment: hi, Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
and also I'm importing the sql file using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bb]> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USER_TRACKS;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> USE USER_TRACKS;
Database changed
MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]>
MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]>
MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]> CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE(
    ->
    -> userId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> firstName VARCHAR(10),
    -> lastName VARCHAR(10),
    -> contactNo VARCHAR(20),
    -> emailId VARCHAR(30),
    -> pass VARCHAR(30)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]>
MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]> CREATE TABLE USER_MUSIC_CATALOGUE(
    ->
    -> userId INT REFERENCES USER_TABLE(userId),
    -> generType VARCHAR(20),
    -> albumName VARCHAR(20),
    -> artistName VARCHAR(20),
    -> releaseDate DATE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [USER_TRACKS]>
```